# Migrating Postgres to Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-postgres

Can we migrate directly from postgres to Redis. I was trying with npm package 
"postgres-redis" but got stuck.I have huge data stored in Postgres DB in m local, I want this data to be migrated to Redis.How this can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

You can import your Postgres tables into Redis using this tool: https://github.com/Redislabs-Solution-Architects/riot

See the 'Import databases" section of the readme.

You will need to use the Postgres JDBC driver documented here : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-use.html